# Issue with my SQL Constraint in my INSERT statement

Tags: sql

[Screenshot of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3HAm.png)I created a table with the following command. When I try and enter values with an insert commaand I get an error. I will also attach a screenshot of the Query if that helps.

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>  The INSERT statement conflicted
> with the CHECK constraint "CK__DogLicense__Sex__1BC821DD". The
> conflict occurred in database "TWalls_W23", table "dbo.DogLicense",
> column 'Sex'.
>  The statement has been terminated.

Completion time: 2023-02-28T04:25:27.8103515-08:00

```
CREATE TABLE DogLicense (

    License int identity (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Expires date check (Expires > '01/01/1990'),
    Sex char(30) Check(Sex in ('M','F','NM','SF')) ,
    PetName char(30),
    Breed char(30),
    OwnerLastname char(30),
    OwnerFirstName char(30),
    Address char(30),
    Zip char(30) check(Zip > '99201' and Zip < '99212'),
    Phone char(30) default ('555) 555-5555'))

insert DogLicense values(null,'03/21/2023','F','Sam','Border Collie', 'Jeff,Dunham','144 Widow Ln.','99217','(509) 555-1414')
```

I know it's an issue with the costraint on sex. I'm not sure what the issue is exactly.

Comment: A possibly related issue is that you are inserting a NULL value into your primary key field, which you have specified as NOT NULL (not accepting NULLs).

Comment: A date has nothing to do with sex. Your error occurs because you were very lazy not to list your update columns.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you’re using. Answers vary materially between each.

Comment: `values(null,`  - drop this item. By default IDENTITY INSERT option is OFF, you must not provide value for this column.

Comment: Sorry, Using Microsoft SQL

Comment: And unrelated, if you have such a check for sex, wouldn't it be better to have the column type as Varchar(2).

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't lazy and erronously rely on column order, there wouldn't be any problems:

```
insert DogLicense
 (
    Expires, Sex, PetName, Breed, 
    OwnerLastname, OwnerFirstName,
    Address, Zip, Phone)

) values 
('20230321','F','Sam','Border Collie', 
 'Jeff', 'Dunham',
 '144 Widow Ln.','99217','(509) 555-1414');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Didn't intend to be lazy I was just following how my class told me to do it.

Comment: @TimW, I see. Then stop listening to your class teacher and read it from tutorials online.

Comment: @TimW - or to put it another way, this is a simple, obvious, bad habit. If they're going to teach this as an example, you have to wonder how many other *bad* habits they'll give you whilst "teaching" you SQL. And unfortunately, if you're new to SQL you don't have a good way to gauge the quality of their teaching.